# Iexpress error Unable to open makeCab file

Tags: windows, installation

I am trying to make a security file to sell it in my website so I need an installation file. I tried to use IExpress but when I come to the last step (which is create package) it shows the following error:

> Unable to open makeCAB directive.

My package contains an icon file, a registry file, an executable and some batch and command files. Is there any other programs that I can use to create an installation file? When I try to open my existing SED files it says:

> Unable to open report file .rpt.

How can I fix this?

Windows 7 pro
64-bit

Comment: Is this an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry you had to wait so long for an answer, but I just had this issue and accidentally found the solution:
when run IExpress Wizard, make sure you Run as Administrator. 
That's it. You'd think [a wikihow for this subject](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Exe-File) would have included a tidbit like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was getting unable to open cab file.
I was creating SED file using a script and i missed a header [SourceFiles] for source files section.I added that line and it got resolved.